# Are there any go-to resources for how to grab users or readers attention?

Tags: resource-recommendations

When a reader looks at a magazine, their eyes may dart to different things on a page in a particular order. I have seen graphs of this and it's astounding how much surface area the eye can cover. I also know designers take advantage of this trying to influence readers perceptions by creating visual effects that grab attention. I just use magazines as an example because I've had the most experience with them. But this obviously applies to a large range of different kinds of creative mediums such as web design, TV, art, and more.

I would like to read more about attention and ways to design my spreads or web pages in ways that grab attention more effectively. What are some of the well-regarded resources people  consult on this matter?

I study neuroscience and various forms of psychology, but a lot of neuroscience literature isn't written to be practical. I'm looking for resources to help my designs by understanding the process of attention-grabbing from a designer's perspective.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. To answer broadly, designers use all sorts of things: color, balance, weight, contrast, scale, pattern, repetition, white space, symmetry, asymmetry, etc, etc. It's sort of like "how does a carpenter build a house?" It's a good question, but too broad for StackExchange.

Comment: Maybe I need to edit it then. I don't want information on how to attract attention. That is too broad and isn't what I want info on. I was hoping someone with both a background in design and psychology could answer who had engaged or read about eye-tracking experiments. It's how design elements influence thetrajectory of the eye that i am interested in and what this tells us about the psychology of interest in the material itself.

Comment: That's still rather broad/vague. The catch is that context is everything. What draws attention in one context may be completely ignored in another.

Comment: I see your point. Well, maybe it is too broad then. I am new to GD.SE so I am trying to get a feel for what makes for a good and useful question here. This may have missed the mark so to speak and not be specific enough to be useful. I can close / delete it if that's sensible.

Comment: I am but one opinion. So don't close or delete it yet! Other's may suggest some tweaks. Again, I think it's a good question. Just needs some narrowing down. Hopefully others can chime in.

Comment: Shoot on my old laptop I've got a few articles on this topic bookmarked. I'll boot it up when I get home and link em for you. Hope you stick around, would love to get answers from the neuro side of things. Eye movement studies are so interesting to me.

Comment: I guess what it can be narrowed down to is "how can I structure my design/layout to bring attention to certain aspects of it?" But that's still an extremely broad question. In order to be a bit more helpful though, [here's](http://www.visualmess.com) a decent read on structuring your design to communicate more clearly. It's far from perfect but will help introduce a few core concepts of good design. Beyond that I'd suggest looking up lists of good design books to get you started on learning graphic design. There are a few such questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Before and After magazine: http://www.bamagazine.com
- they specialise in teaching design in a very easy to access way. You can see some of their work for free, and if there is a particular issue you are interested in that is not free, they can be downloaded for around $4 each.

I know for a fact that they have extensive resources teaching ways to use design to grab the viewer's attention in ordered, communicative and beautiful ways. There are many many glowing testimonials on their website from satisfied subscribers.